# Lottie animation is not working as expected

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, lottie

I am using a Lottie file for animation purpose. It is not loading as expected. It should be like this http://www.lottiefiles.com/48-progress-bar

Current State: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgvj9pss2cauv37/device-2017-04-03-113913.mp4?dl=0

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.icici.iciciappathon.checkout.PaymentSucessActivity"
    android:background="@color/sky_blue">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:lottie_fileName="progress_bar.json"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with what you are doing. Lottie is pretty straightforward to use. There's a problem with the progress_bar.json unfortunately.

Try to get in touch with the designer and maybe he can fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just changing the dependency did work for me

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.8.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'
```